# implementing face id in android in flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I have to implement face id to my flutter project, the problem is that flutter package local_auth does not support face id in android. I know that in native android app it is possile to implemant face id. My question  is there any method to implement face id in android module and then use it in flutter code. If it is possible, how to do this?

Comment: You didn't find: https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_ml_vision

Comment: This is not face id, is it ?

Comment: You are correct. I thought you were asking about face ML not biometric which is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You sould look at platform channels. This will allow you to communicate between flutter and native code. It would be a too long answer to give you an example but you can look at [this tutorial](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels#example) from the flutter team. There is an example here which could inspire you to achieve what you want.

However it appear that [local_auth does support face id for android](https://pub.dev/packages/local_auth#android-integration).

> On Android, you can check only for existence of fingerprint hardware prior to API 29 (Android Q). Therefore, if you would like to support other biometrics types (such as face scanning) and you want to support SDKs lower than Q, do not call getAvailableBiometrics. Simply call authenticateWithBiometrics. This will return an error if there was no hardware available.